M2.4.7 Csp - what trigger generation of new hash values for csp_whitelist.xml
We have upgraded to M2.4.7 and have had some issues on the checkout page caused by csp blocking scripts loading from Cloudflare.
Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'https://www.xxx.dk/static/version1714545269/frontend/Magento/luma/da_DK/requirejs/require.js' with computed SHA-256 integrity 'VODlv7gms2iTofiNaOF9GqKvi4P0WL3J8UuH2UaX7rE='. The resource has been blocked.

The solution was to disable Cloudflare proxy and everything is working again, but how can use Cloudflare proxy?

What trigger generation of new hash values in Magento for inserting in csp_whitelist.xml . After with commando do i have to update the hash values in csp_whitelist.xml



I'm facing the same Issue with 2.4.6-p6. Did you find a Solution?

FINAL EDIT:
The only thing I've managed to do so far is to set a rule in CloudFlare to not cache URL's with the checkout using Cache Rules or Page Rules.
Inline-Scripts (Side Note):
To generate a nonce for inline scripts, which would be blocked at checkout, you will need $secureRenderer or $csp your script from within a .phtml file. Anything that is in the Configuration / Design footer or header will no longer be allowed.
<?php $menuScript = <<<script
    require(['jquery'], function($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".magicmenu ul").find("[data-categoryid='.$categoryId.']").parent('li').addClass('active');

    });
});
script;
?>

<?= /* @noEscape */ $secureRenderer->renderTag('script', [], $menuScript, false) ?>

Also note, You cannot add $secureRenderer->renderTag to areas that have block_html cache enabled such as the footer. It will cache the nonce and make it impossible to load

Thank you for noticing it was cloudflare!!!!
I have tried turning off all the "auto minify" functions in cloudflare and right now the error has vanished.
Will monitor to see if it was all that was needed
These functions will be deprecated anyway, got to return to minifying on server if wanted
Note that other "javascript modifying" functions or third party plugins in cloudflare might need to be disabled - i'm not using any so I can't tell which
